# How can I change the icons/drag clue when dragging a node in Kendo UI TreeList?

Tags: javascript, events, kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, kendo-treelist

When dragging a node in Kendo TreeList, it shows a plus-icon when e.target is valid (allowed to drop into) but shows a denied-icon when e.target is invalid (for example when you drag a node over itself or a child).
I defined some own conditions where it's denied to drop. 
Now, I want to change the icon to denied according to my rules, too.

For Tree**View**, there is the `e.setStatusClass(k-denied)` method for this. It does not work on a Tree**List**: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/events/drag .
Is there something similar for TreeList? In the docs, there isn't: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist/events/drag .

--

Using an `onDrag(e)` method and accessing `e.target` gives a `td`. But I need the **dataItem** into the `tr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it using the [drag event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist/events/drag)...

I added a drag-function to the treelist:

```
drag: function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).parents('#targetTreeList>div>table').length>0) {
        e.setStatus("k-i-plus");
    }
    else {
        e.setStatus("k-i-cancel");
    }
}
```

And it will change the icon when hovering over nodes in treelist with Id='targetTreeList', of course you can add your own logic (I checked that it was a root node as well)...

I hope I could help a little (my first answer here at stackoverflow...)

Edit:
To get the dataitem you could use:

```
$(e.target).parents('.k-treelist').data('kendoTreeList').dataItem(e.target)
```

(lookes overcomplicated but that was the only way I got it to work)...

Comment: thanks :) e.setStatus does work, but I need the dataitem into the TR I'm dragging to. e.target gives a TD.

Comment: Missed that you needed dataItem, I've updated to add my cumbersome way to get a hold of dataItem ($(e.target).parents('.k-treelist').data('kendoTreeList').dataItem(e.target)).

Comment: I also noticed it afterwards that I need to get the dataitem. Thanks a lot! Stackoverflow has a new very helpful contributor.